# Congruence with power two less than a prime modulus

Tags: modular-arithmetic

We know from Fermat's little theorem that
$$
15^{42} \equiv 1 \mod{43}
$$
since 43 is a prime number and $43 \nmid 15$. Could I use this fact to calculate $15^{41} (mod\ 43)$? My first impression tells me that I can not divide by 15, since is 15 is not a factor of the right hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply the modular inverse of $15 \pmod {43}$.
This exists since $gcd(15,43) = 1$. So we have
$$ 15^{42}\equiv 1 \pmod {43} \Leftrightarrow 15^{41} \equiv 1\cdot (15)^{-1}\pmod {43} \equiv 23\pmod{43}.$$

Comment: Did you use Euclid's algorith to calculate $(15)^{-1}$?

Comment: @Nick In this case it can be done by guessing. But in general you would want to use the (advanced) Euclid Algorithm

Comment: And indeed, you *should* try yourself the extended Euclidean algorithm to find that
$$
-20\cdot 15+7\cdot 43=\gcd(15,23)=1,
$$
so that $-20=23$ is the inverse of $15$ modulo $43$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).